# ODEs - Seperable differential equation, is an explicit answer necessary in an exam?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution for the following first order differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=(1-y)(3-y)(5-t).$$

I end up getting to

$$\exp(10x-x^2+2C)=(y-3)(y-1).$$

Is there any more simplifying that can be done to express $y$ explicitly? Wolfram Alpha has an explicit answer, but that may be due simply to its computational power...

Do you think it is likely, that in an exam, it is required to simplify further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you made a sign error. separating the equation you get $$\dfrac{dy}{(1-y)(3-y)} = (5-t)dt$$  the partial fraction decomposition gives you $$\dfrac{dy}{y-3} - \dfrac{dy}{y-1} = (10 - 2t)\ dt$$ on integration this gives you 
$$\dfrac{y-3}{y-1} = Ce^{10t -t^2}$$

solving the last one for $y$ gives $$y = \dfrac{3-Ce^{10t-t^2}}{1+Ce^{10t-t^2}} $$

Comment: Actually, it turns out I got my log laws mixed up rather then a sign error, haha. I was trying to multiply the log parameters rather than divide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you are able to derive an explicit solution, then it is necessary to present it on your test paper, but if it is literally not possible to derive, (for example, $y+10sin(y)-e^{x}-2ln(x)=0$) then an implicit solution will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{dy}{(1-y)(3-y)} = (5-t)dt$.

Or starting where you left off, solve for $y$ using **Quadratic Formula**

Comment: I get to $y(y-4)=exp(10x-x^2+@C)-3$, then I get stuck.

That's after I expand RHS to get $y^2-4y+3$.